# How to display the contents of expect_out(buffer) in expect

Tags: expect

I am using simple expect script which waits for "hi" and displays contents in the buffer. The script is not able to print the contents of the script. I have tried all the 4 various ways (those which are commented) for displaying the expect_out(buffer). Suggest any changes/ modifications in the below script

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/usr/bin/expect

expect "hi\r"

#puts "$expect_out(buffer)"
#send_user "$expect_out(buffer)\n"
#send "you typed <$expect_out(buffer)\r>"
#send "but I only expected <$expect_out(buffer)\r>"
```

The following error is prompted " can't read "expect_out(0,string)": no such variable
    while executing
"puts "$expect_out(0,string)""
    (file "./oreilly.exp" line 7) "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when debugging an expect script, put `exp_internal 1` at the top of the script.

when expecting, you should expect `\n` not `\r`

to see what's in expect_out, use this handy Tcl command: `parray expect_out`